# PS functions in function, how to call second time

Tags: powershell, sccm

I have a script which compairing registry time values, and server time values. as well i have a sccm simple fix script. and main thing which i am trying to achieve is to call registry and server time values two times in the main script. (before and after) and i stuttering as i cant understand why my compairing script is not working second time or it showing the same time as at the first run
script:

```
#SCCM script START
Function Get-Sccm-Repair-test_01 {
PARAM(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true)]
    [string]$computer
)
###############
#Start Trigering Application Deployment Evaluation Cycle#
        Function get-sccm-reg-values {
param(
    [string]$computer
   ,[string]$Path= "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Danskebank\Agent Status"
   ,[string[]]$Properties
   ,[switch]$Verbose
)

if ($Verbose) { $VerbosePreference = 2 }

   $root, $last = $Path.Split("\")
   $last = $last[-1]
   $Path = $Path.Substring($root.Length + 1,$Path.Length - ( $last.Length + $root.Length + 2))
   $root = $root.TrimEnd(":")
   switch($root) {
      "HKCR"  { $root = "ClassesRoot"}
      "HKCU"  { $root = "CurrentUser" }
      "HKLM"  { $root = "LocalMachine" }
      "HKU"   { $root = "Users" }
      "HKPD"  { $root = "PerformanceData"}
      "HKCC"  { $root = "CurrentConfig"}
      "HKDD"  { $root = "DynData"}
      default { return "Path argument is not valid" }
   }
   #Access Remote Registry Key using the static OpenRemoteBaseKey method.
   Write-Verbose "Accessing $root from $computer"
   $rootkey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($root,$computer)
   if(-not $rootkey) { Write-Error "Can't open the remote $root registry hive" }

   Write-Verbose "Opening $Path"
   $key = $rootkey.OpenSubKey( $Path )
   if(-not $key) { Write-Error "Can't open $($root + '\' + $Path) on $computer" }
   $subkey = $key.OpenSubKey( $last )
   $output = new-object object

   if($subkey -and $Properties -and $Properties.Count) {
      foreach($property in $Properties) {
        Add-Member -InputObject $output -Type NoteProperty -Name $property -Value $subkey.GetValue($property)
      }
      Write-Output $output
      } elseif($subkey) {
        foreach($property in $subkey.GetValueNames()) 
      {
        Add-Member -InputObject $output -Type NoteProperty -Name $property -Value $subkey.GetValue($property)
      }

}
        $pcTime = invoke-command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {Get-Date -DisplayHint Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd}

        $SCCMValue = $pcTime | Out-String
        $Rserver = $output.SCCMTimestamp | Out-String

        if($SCCMValue -eq $Rserver)
        {
            Write-Host -foreground "green"  "Server curent date:" $pcTime
            Write-Host -foreground "green"  "SCCM Registry Value is up to date:" $output.SCCMTimestamp
        }
        else
        {
           Write-Host -foreground "red" "Server curent date:" $pcTime
           Write-Host -foreground "red" "SCCM Registry Value is outdate:" $output.SCCMTimestamp
        }
    $key = Out-Null
    $pcTime = Out-Null
 }

#END Trigering Application Deployment Evaluation Cycle#
###############

        ###############
        #Start Trigering Application Deployment Evaluation Cycle#
        $SCCMClient = [wmiclass] "\\$computer\root\ccm:SMS_client"
        Write-Host -foreground "green" "Application Deployment Evaluation Cycle Updated"
        $SCCMClient.TriggerSchedule("{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000121}") | Out-Null

        Write-Host -foreground "green" "Machine Policy Retrieval and Evaluation Cycle Updated"
        $SCCMClient.TriggerSchedule("{00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000021}") | Out-Null
        #Stop Trigering Application Deployment Evaluation Cycle#
        ###############

        Write-Host -foreground "green" "Gathering data for pending install packages..."
        $SoftwareApp = Get-WmiObject -Namespace  ROOT\ccm\ClientSDK -Class CCM_Application -ComputerName $computer | Select-Object AllowedActions, Fullname | FT -AutoSize
        Write-Host -foreground "green" "Installing Deployment Test (SCCMTimestamp) package..."

        #Start Trigering the SCCM package#
        $AppName = "Deployment Test (SCCMTimestamp)"

        $s = New-PSSession -ComputerName $Computer
        Invoke-Command -Session $s -Argu $Computer,$AppName -ScriptBlock `
        {
        param ($Computer,$AppName)
        write-host "Getting Parameters for '$AppName' on $Computer"
        $App = Get-WmiObject -computername $Computer -Namespace "root\ccm\ClientSDK" -Class CCM_Application | where {$_.Name -like "$AppName"} | Select-Object Id, Revision, IsMachineTarget
        $AppID = $App.Id
        $AppRev = $App.Revision
        $AppTarget = $App.IsMachineTarget
        write-host $AppID, $AppRev, $AppTarget -ForegroundColor Yellow
        write-host "Triggering Installation!" -ForegroundColor Green
        ([wmiclass]'ROOT\ccm\ClientSdk:CCM_Application').Install($AppID, $AppRev, $AppTarget, 0, 'Normal', $False) | Out-Null
        }
        Remove-PSSession $s
        #End Trigering the SCCM package#

        #Restarting the service.START
        Write-Host -foreground "green" "Restarting the HealthService..."
        $session = New-PSsession -Computername $computer
        Invoke-Command -Session $Session -ScriptBlock {Restart-Service "HealthService"} | Out-Null
        Remove-PSSession $Session
        #Resstarting the service.END

        ################ Double check the time START
        Function get-sccm-reg-values {
param(
    [string]$Path     = "HKLM\SOFTWARE\Danskebank\Agent Status"
   ,[string[]]$Properties
   ,[switch]$Verbose
)

if ($Verbose) { $VerbosePreference = 2 }

   $root, $last = $Path.Split("\")
   $last = $last[-1]
   $Path = $Path.Substring($root.Length + 1,$Path.Length - ( $last.Length + $root.Length + 2))
   $root = $root.TrimEnd(":")
   switch($root) {
      "HKCR"  { $root = "ClassesRoot"}
      "HKCU"  { $root = "CurrentUser" }
      "HKLM"  { $root = "LocalMachine" }
      "HKU"   { $root = "Users" }
      "HKPD"  { $root = "PerformanceData"}
      "HKCC"  { $root = "CurrentConfig"}
      "HKDD"  { $root = "DynData"}
      default { return "Path argument is not valid" }
   }
   #Access Remote Registry Key using the static OpenRemoteBaseKey method.
   Write-Verbose "Accessing $root from $computer"
   $rootkey = [Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey]::OpenRemoteBaseKey($root,$computer)
   if(-not $rootkey) { Write-Error "Can't open the remote $root registry hive" }

   Write-Verbose "Opening $Path"
   $key = $rootkey.OpenSubKey( $Path )
   if(-not $key) { Write-Error "Can't open $($root + '\' + $Path) on $computer" }
   $subkey = $key.OpenSubKey( $last )
   $output = new-object object

   if($subkey -and $Properties -and $Properties.Count) {
      foreach($property in $Properties) {
        Add-Member -InputObject $output -Type NoteProperty -Name $property -Value $subkey.GetValue($property)
      }
      Write-Output $output
      } elseif($subkey) {
        foreach($property in $subkey.GetValueNames()) 
      {
        Add-Member -InputObject $output -Type NoteProperty -Name $property -Value $subkey.GetValue($property)
      }

}
        $pcTime = invoke-command -ComputerName $computer -ScriptBlock {Get-Date -DisplayHint Date -Format yyyy-MM-dd}

        $SCCMValue = $pcTime | Out-String
        $Rserver = $output.SCCMTimestamp | Out-String

        if($SCCMValue -eq $Rserver)
        {
            Write-Host -foreground "green"  "Server curent date:" $pcTime
            Write-Host -foreground "green"  "SCCM Registry Value is up to date:" $output.SCCMTimestamp
        }
        else
        {
           Write-Host -foreground "red" "Server curent date:" $pcTime
           Write-Host -foreground "red" "SCCM Registry Value is outdate:" $output.SCCMTimestamp
        }
 }
        ############### Double check the time END

        Write-Host -foreground "green" "SCCM fix has been performed, please wait from 5 to 10 minutes untill event close in scom.."
}
#SCCM script END
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I don't see where you are actually invoking the function. You declare the get-sccm-reg-values function, but never run it. Then later on you declare it again which would overwrite the first declaration but again you never actually invoke it.
Try declaring both functions but then calling one from inside the other. For example:

```
#Create a function
function foo{
param()
  return Get-Date
}
#create second function
function bar{
param()
  #functions have to be called to do anything
  foo
  Start-Sleep -Seconds 2
  #call the same function again
  foo
}

#Call the second function
bar
```